# How to allow users to copy files with different user and group?

Tags: permissions, nginx

Good Day,

There is a linux user and group called "developers" (has no sudo access) with home folder in "/home/developers".

There is nginx running on the same server, there is a web folder for a site called "mysite.com". that web folder is in "/usr/local/nginx/html/mysite.com/" Folder site rights are "nginx:developers" and chmod permissions are 770. Now here comes the problem.

Users "scp" their files into the server using "developers" user. Files get stored in "/home/developers" folder WITH "developers" owner (obviously). Users have to copy those files into "/usr/local/nginx/html/mysite.com/" folder. After "developers" user copies files lets say "testfile.py" into "/usr/local/nginx/html/mysite.com/" owner of the file stays as "developers:developers". Therefore, nginx can not read the file.

How can I make that work? How can I allow user "developers" to transfer files into "/usr/local/nginx/html/mysite.com/" with nginx:nginx permissions? (without giving sudo access). Or what can I do on group level to make sure nginx will read those files?

Edit: nginx and php-fpm running as "nginx"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what can I do on group level to make sure nginx will read those files?

It doesn't sound like there would be any particular issue with putting the `nginx` user into the `developers` group:

As root:

```
usermod -a -G developers nginx
```

A user can be in multiple groups.  You can see which ones `nginx` is currently in with:

```
grep nginx /etc/group
# Or more simply:
id nginx
```

If putting `nginx` in `developers` poses some problem, you'll have to create a new group, put both the `nginx` and `developers` user in that, and make sure the transferred files have that GID.

Note that you must log in again before new group memberships become available.  For non-login accounts (presumably `nginx` is one) you can just use `su` or start a process which does the same (in this case, the nginx server itself should work).

Comment: Instead of the grep you could also use `getent group nginx` and `id nginx`.

Comment: @goldilocks     what i will explain now will sound too moronic of me. I had tried what you have suggested before (friday). Developers had complained that nginx was giving forbidden error. Apparently, I had to restart nginx after editing user and group permissions. I just don't know what to say at this point. Speechless. I could never think of that one... Microsoft moment for a while...

Comment: Whoops, yeah -- forgot to mention you need to log in again for changes like that to take affect.  If it is a non-login account, try `su nginx` and then test permissions.  You would then have to restart any processes running as that user (I've added a couple of sentences about this).

Comment: yeap nginx is a user without shell and home dir so since Friday I have been dealing with its permissions and forgetting to restart the service and flushing privileges (a huge facepalm)...